How can I fix the "Can't open timeline using this device" error when trying to migrate to my timeline to be on-device?
I recently received an email from Google telling me to migrate my timeline to be on-device. When I clicked the "review settings" option from the email, it opened my google maps app.
After loading for a few seconds, it would display an error reading, "Can't open timeline on this type of device. To keep going back in time, use the Google Maps app on a supported smartphone. Important: Timeline isn't avaliable on Android Go devices."

The strange thing is, my device isn't running Android Go. Here are my device details:

Device Make: Pixel 6a
OS Version: Android 15 (Build AP4A.241205.013)

Security Patch: December 5, 2024,
Google Play System Update: November 1, 2024


Google Maps Version (from in-app): 24.50.01.704483103 (#1067838727)
Google Play Services Version (from system settings): version 24.47.61 (260400-704347912)
Google Play Store Version (from in-app): 43.9.17-31 [O] [PR] 700738295
Phone not rooted, have entered and exited android public beta multiple times through non-wipe exits (QPRs)

Troubleshooting steps I've already taken:

Restart device
Check for Android updates, app updates (in Google Play Store), and Google Play System Updates (in device settings)
Clear Cache and Data of Google Maps, Google Play Store, and Google Play Services

Related Google Help Article: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/14169818
What haven't I tried yet that could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Update: I recently received an on-device notification from the Google Maps app asking me to migrate my timeline to be on-device (with similar wording to the email). Tapping the notification led to the same error mentioned above.
The notification read as follows:
"Keep your timeline?" "Timeline is changing. To avoid losing visits and routes, update your settings by Jun 9."

Is the phone rooted? AFAIK, Android Go is determined by the value of ro.config.low_ram in build.prop. (Ref: Disable Android Go?)

@andrew-t Phone not rooted, running stock software. Although I have entered and left the Android beta program through no-wipe exit updates (through QPRs). Maybe that has something to do with it? Will update question later with this info.
